# iOS issue with login to dropbox with different users in same app

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I have done dropbox integration in my app. For that i have created application in developer portal of dropbox.Generates the key and secrets and integrated in the application. My problem is i want to give the login facility to different user so that they can access my dropbox features integrated in the app natively by after login. Can anyone help me for the same.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I'm not totally clear on your question, but this sounds like the normal use pattern for the Dropbox API. The API is designed with the intention that you implement the app authorization flow into your app so that each user can link to their own account and interact with their own files. I recommend working through the tutorial for whichever SDK you're using: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios

Comment: @Greg, Sir, i have done my implementation in the same way as your provide link No 1. But my question is . if i have created one app using "abc" login credentials then use key and secrets of those generated app inside my iphone app ...in such case if i try to login in to dropbox using the other credential say "xyz"..it does not authenticate. What i want is i should login to dropbox with any credential .which means any user can login and can see his dropbox files after login using my dropbox integrated app.(here in my case i am using for list of music file which i am downloading).

Comment: That is how this should work. Are you getting an error message when you try to link a different account?

Comment: @Greg ..Sir, when i try to login with different credential..it is giving me message as "Only a limited set of user can access token while this app is in development mode". is there anything wrong i am doing please suggest me.Thanks

Comment: When you first register your app, only your own account can link to it. You can use the "Enable additional users" button on your app's page on the App Console ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps ) to let up to 100 users link to your app while it's in development mode. This limit doesn't apply once your app is switched to production mode.

Comment: @Greg, Sir, It is now login with different account as you suggested . Thank you for helping me . But i have one saviour issue now i am getting crash after long button press though it gets logged in i see crash "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Unsupported Signature Method', reason: 'The signature method "(null)" is not currently support by MPOAuthConnection'" I dont understand whats wrong i am doing

Comment: @Greg...I just found your comment in portal regarding my crash report...i.e..."Make sure you clear all your DBRestClient objects when you unlink. If you try to use an old DBRestClient object it will cause this problem.".. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can find some more information about that issue in this thread: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=94511#post-594767

Comment: @Greg...Thanks it works for me .It is very useful talk with you. Thanks for your valuable time sir

Comment: @Greg ..I have one question . How do u check whether Device already contains dropbox app install and login with some user, Since user logged in already from dropbox, my app wont ask for login . how to check that condition. Please reply me asap .thanks sir

Comment: There's no official/documented way to check, but you shouldn't need to. If the user doesn't want to use the already logged in account, they have the choice to use a different one.